# Problems Implementing AR, ARMA, and possibly more complex timeseries models in pymc3 using theano.scan

Tags: time-series, pymc3, autoregressive-models

I try to implement a simple ARMA model, however have serious difficulties getting it to run. When adding a parameter to the error term everything works fine (see the `return x_m1 + a*e` statement, commented out below), however if I add a parameter to the auto regressive part, I get a `FloatingPointError` or `LinAlgError` or `PositiveDefiniteError`, depending on the initialization method I use.

The code is also put into a [gist you can find here](https://gist.github.com/1980c0711ead4e38045b4b03a454c3bb). The model definition is replicated here:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    a = pm.Normal("a", 0, 1)
    sigma = pm.Exponential('sigma', 0.1, testval=F(.1))
    e = pm.Normal("e", 0, sigma, shape=(N-1,))

    def x(e, x_m1, a):
        # return x_m1 + a*e
        return a*x_m1 + e

    x, updates = theano.scan(
        fn=x,
        sequences=[e],
        outputs_info=[tt.as_tensor_variable(data.iloc[0])],
        non_sequences=[a]
    )
    x = pm.Deterministic('x', x)

    lam = pm.Exponential('lambda', 5.0, testval=F(.1))
    y = pm.StudentT("y", mu=x, lam=lam, nu=1, observed=data.values[1:]) # 

with model:
    trace = pm.sample(2000, init="NUTS", n_init=1000)
```

Here the errors respective to the initialization methods:

"ADVI" / "ADVI_MAP": `FloatingPointError: NaN occurred in ADVI optimization.`

"MAP": `LinAlgError: 35-th leading minor not positive definite`

"NUTS": `PositiveDefiniteError: Scaling is not positive definite. Simple check failed. Diagonal contains negatives. Check indexes [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]`

For details on the error messages, please look at [this github issue posted at pymc3](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1973).

To be explicit, I really would like to have a scan-like solution which is easily extendable to for instance a full ARMA model. I know that one can represent the presented AR(1) model without scan by defining `logP` as already done in pymc3/distributions/timeseries.py#L18-L46, however I was not able to extend this vectorized style  to a full ARMA model. The use of `theano.scan` seems preferable I think.

Any help is highly appriciated!